# Getting An Error When Deleting Cell From Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I delete a cell from my table, i am getting the following error:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
>       Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate
>   of NSFetchedResultsController during a
>   call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. 
>   Invalid update: invalid number of rows
>   in section 0.  The number of rows
>   contained in an existing section after
>   the update (5) must be equal to the
>   number of rows contained in that
>   section before the update (5), plus or
>   minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted). with userInfo (null)

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Update the array and table view.
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.resultsTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.resultsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.resultsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.resultsTableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.resultsTableView endUpdates];
}
```

I tried removing `[self.setsTableView reloadData];` from the last method but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **self.fetchedResultsController**  to fetchedResultsController in all the above methods. Just keep self.fetchedResultsController only in method

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

//--Try to keep managedObjectContext as a member variable and use the following setter //method.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
```

```
if (managedObjectContext != nil) 
{
    return managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];   
if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return managedObjectContext;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, but I don't even have a numberOfSectionsInTableView Method.  Do you mean numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: NO, I mean numberOfSectionsInTableView only. Can you zip and send the .h and .m file of your viewcontroller?

Comment: Thanks Adarsh.  I've zipped and linked the .h and .m files here: http://www.box.net/shared/static/9gaqho979f.zip

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, so should I remove `self.managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];` from `-viewDidLoad` and call the method you provided instead?

Comment: yes thanks, but i thought i'm only supposed to do `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator` in the app delegate?

Comment: Yup NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is created in appdelegate only. But here you are access it by a pointer in the viewcontroller. This line do thatNSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];

Answer (score 1):

seems like you're deleting the cell from the table, but not deleting the object from the table datasource, which creates an inconsistency.
try adding something like:

```
[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

when you use `tableView:deleteRowsAtIndexes`

the number returned by `numberOfRowsInSection:` must by the same as the number of rows in your tableView, minus/plus the ones you've deleted/added